# Updating an item in a FirebaseListObservable using AngularFire 2

Tags: angular, angularfire

I'm trying to update an item in a [FirebaseListObservable](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#example-use) object in an Angular2 project using Angularfire2. The definition for the FirebaseListObservable is as follows:

```
export declare type FirebaseOperation = string | firebase.database.Reference | firebase.database.DataSnapshot | AFUnwrappedDataSnapshot;
export declare class FirebaseListObservable<T> extends Observable<T> {
  _ref: firebase.database.Reference | firebase.database.Query;
  constructor(_ref: firebase.database.Reference | firebase.database.Query, subscribe?: <R>(subscriber: Subscriber<R>) => Subscription | Function | void);
  lift<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R>;
  push(val: any): firebase.database.ThenableReference;
  update(item: FirebaseOperation, value: Object): firebase.Promise<void>;
  remove(item?: FirebaseOperation): firebase.Promise<void>;
  _checkOperationCases(item: FirebaseOperation, cases: FirebaseOperationCases): firebase.Promise<void>;
}
```

I have a service to show, save, delete, and update the houses that looks like the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class HousesService {
  private _houses$:FirebaseListObservable<IHouse[]>;
  constructor(private af:AngularFire) {
    this._houses$ = this.af.database.list('/houses');
  }
  save(house:IHouse) {
    if (house.hasOwnProperty('$key')) {
      this._houses.update('/houses/'+house.$key).set(house);
    } else {
      this._houses$.push(house);
    }
  }
  remove(id:any) {
    this._houses$.remove(id);
  }
}
```

where `houses$` is the `FirebaseListObservable` and `house` is an item from the list. House is an object that looks like the following:

```
{
  name: "Mrs. Friendly", 
  notes: "Watch out for fence!", 
  street: "2530 Adams Ave.", 
  $key: "-KKQWsf26apDiXZNExZd"
 }
```

When I try to save/update an existing item, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains an
>   invalid key ($key) in path /$key. Keys must be non-empty strings and
>   can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

I've tried putting the original object in the first parameter, putting the full URL there, and almost every combination you can think of. According to the definition for the Observable, the _ref should work there as well. I've also tried pulling the key out of the data to be stored and nothing seems to work. The only thing that seems to work is to remove the update line completely and use the following:

```
this.af.database.object('/houses/'+house.$key).set(house);
```

I'm curious what I should have put in the first parameter so the update method would work.

I'm using Angular 2 rc-1, firebase 3.0.5, and angularfire 2.0.0-beta.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version of Angularfire is slightly older than mine but for your save method, I think you can just pass the key of the house to save (house.$key) along with an object containing the updated data.

```
this._houses.update(house.$key, house);
```

I think by passing the '/houses/' part, the error is being thrown because the $key can't start with '/'.

Comment: This is along the right line, but for the second argument, I needed to just put the updated data, so it looks more like this._houses.update(house.$key, {lat:1234, lng: 5678}). Putting the original object in causes a conflict on the key.

Comment: @jloosli Thanks for the comment. The object's key needs to be removed in the second argument.

key = house.$key;
delete house.$key;
this._houses.update(key, house);

Answer (score 1):

```
var key = house.$key
delete house.$key
this._houses.update(key, house)
```